# Why context object as the parameter in the TextView constructor and the explicit Intent constructor is written in a different way?

Tags: java, android

Why context object as the parameter in the TextView constructor and the explicit Intent constructor is written in a different way?
Correct initialization includes：

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
```

But when I'm trying to write:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
```

An error noticed was displayed. I don't understand the difference between **this** and **MainActivity.this**. Anyone could explain what they really are and how to distinguish them?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your code is but I guess you're using `this` in the wrong place ! Generally `this` refers to the `class` that `this` keyword is currently within, If you use `this` in an inner class actually you're referring to the inner class not the outer one, for example let assume we have these lines of code in the `onCreate` method of `MainActivity` :

```
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView tv;
            //Wrong way
            tv = new TextView(this);//this refers to onClickListener (inner class)
            //It's ok
            tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

            Intent i;
            //Wrong way
            i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);//this refers to the onClickListener (inner class)
            //It's ok 
            i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        }
    });
```

It's self explanatory, always be careful about **what you expect as `this` and where you use `this`**

it's a good practice to mention the `class` name before `this` keyword like : `MainActivity.this`